# How to prevent multiple HTTP requests in GraphQL resolver

Tags: graphql

Edit: I think the crux of my question is: how do one pass data between two resolvers?

I am currently writing a GraphQL layer over a rest endpoint. The JSON returned by one of the endpoint looks like this:

```
{
 id: 123
 timestamp: 12232786374394
 foo: foo-string
}
```

Where `foo-string` is an key, with which the `Foo` object can be retrieved from another endpoint. So let's say that `http://server/api/foo/foo-string` will return the following json:

```
{
 foo-id: 77
 foo-name: joe
 foo-active: true
}
```

The problem now is with writing a resolver for the `Foo` object. In the resolver function I can access the `foo-string` value via the `parent` argument and I can then use this to retrieve the JSON. The problem now is, I need to make this http call for every field and no way to resuse the result.

so for example if a graphql like this is made:

```
query {
 id,
 timestamp,
 foo {
    foo-id,
    foo-name,
    foo-active
 }
}
```

Then `foo-id`, `foo-name` and `foo-active` will trigger the same HTTP request. Is there a way to prevent this? Where the result of the http request can be reused? (similar to how the parent value is reused)

I am thinking of caching the result of the http request, and check this before making a request in the resolver implementation, but not sure if this is the recommended approach.

Comment: one `foo` resolver calling sequentially `/foo` and `/foo/foo-string` endpoints (if no `extend`-like param to return children at once from `/foo`) ... no separate field resolvers (`foo-id`, `foo-name`, `foo-active`) needed

Comment: but that would lead to over fetching

Comment: REST was better? ...  foo resolver is called only when sub-fields are requested ... over fetching vs. over-requesting, choose one ... you can use resolver `info` to fetch and return only required fields, but probably it's not worth the effort ... like refactoring rest to graphql